# EPiServer: A site with siteId is already registered

Tags: episerver

My EPiServer application is throwing following error:

> A site with siteId is already registered. Call the Reset method firs.

There were no code changes before the exception occurred and there is duplicate of this instance which is running without any problems.

My first try was the most obvious, to change the site id in web.config to something else. This did not help. However changing the configuration restarted application and after refreshing the page it shown another exception:

> This slave site failed when validating master license information

After another refresh, third exception appeared:

> ClassFactory not initialized

Following refreshes bring back original exception about duplicated site id.

I have no idea what could happen. Searching in google did not bring any results. Every restart of the application (through iisreset or by configuration change) causes the site to throw all those three exceptions, always in the same order: license, class factory, and until next restart duplicated site id.

I will be very grateful for any help that could lead me to the solution.

**EDIT: I am using EPiServer 5**

**EDIT 2:** I am now pretty sure that "A site with siteid ..." exception is not relevant here. It is just a consequence of previous fail.
This is what is happening basing on exceptions (it does not seem very logical, but well):

1. IIS is started
2. Application reaches static initializer and tries to validate the master license. It fails, exception is thrown and the site is not yet registered (in the database there is no entry made in tblSiteConfig)
3. The page is refreshed
4. Application reaches static initializer and **successfully validates the license,** the site is then registered, the code goes further and fails on plugin initialization method (class factory not initialized)
5. The page is refreshed
6. Application reaches static initializer and again successfully validates the license, the site fails because it was already registered
7. Step 6 is happening until next IIS restart

Comment: Make sure someone else isn't using the same database from another EPi.

Comment: Check associated the user accounts haven't been disabled or deleted (had same error and that was the issue)

Answer (score 0):

According to messages, is looks like you are using EPiServer Multisite feature.

First thing to check are `/sites/site` sections of `episerver.config` - they should contain different `siteId` attribute.

Next, in `episerver.framework.config` file, clear `siteHostMapping` section, so it should be completely empty:

```
<siteHostMapping />
```

Then, start sites one by one.

Possible cause to issue is exception during site startup - so you can still experience similar or the same issue if these errors won't be fixed. Be sure to turn on logging and examine logs.

Comment: I have only one site. I mean in single config there is only one site. Then this config is deployed on two different servers. I think the main problem is with first two exceptions. The third one, about duplicated siteId, might be just a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

After you've changed the siteId you need to clear some tables in the database. I don't have a EPi5-database at hand but I recall it's at least tblSite.

Comment: This is mainly for the error "This slave site failed when validating master license information".